# Monitoring slow queries and progress in PostgreSQL with restricted user access

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a user with restricted privileges in our PostgreSQL database. This user can view processes in the pg_stat_activity table but cannot access information about their current state or the queries being executed. I also need to run a particularly slow query and provide an API to monitor its progress. Therefore, I am seeking for method to determine whether the query has completed or is still running. One potential approach I've considering is to obtain the process ID (PID) and use it to select the corresponding process in the pg_stat_activity table.
How can I implement this approach to effectively monitor the progress of slow queries and determine their completion status?

The REST API should look like this:

DELETE /products/{id} // takes a lot of time, returns operation ID for monitoring purposes, our application needs to persist the PostgreSQL PID

GET /operations/{id} // Checks whether the delete query has finished via the PID

Comment: You cannot assess how long a running query will take. PostgreSQL has no idea either.

Comment: If a slow query started and is not currently running, then it must have finished.  But how would it know that one had started in the first place?  Are you going to have one process notify another process that it is about to start a slow query?  And wouldn't the controlling process know when the query is finished based on the fact that it got the results back?

Comment: @jjanes I've edited the question with more details how the REST API should look like.

Comment: On the database there should be a process as jjanes said to monitor all process or when you start your job you should another process on the database to monitor it. The thing is why do you need something like this, to detect slow queries or to kill them? If you just want to monitor those processes and do not nothing about it, it would be masochistic :). If you want to detect slow queries you can check pg_stat_statements and pg_sentinel extension. Also, cybertec has nice blogs about it.

Comment: It's not possible to monitor progress. You can only see if a process is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the process call `select pg_backend_pid()` to get the pid of the process which is running queries on its behalf, and send that pid to a monitoring process.  It could then monitor completion (but not progress, in any useful way) trivially.  But this doesn't really make sense unless you are trying to run the statement in the background, as otherwise the controlling process monitors completion itself automatically.  And if you are trying to run the statement in the background, how will you disentangle the backend from the controlling process, without accidentally cancelling it?  This can be tricky, and could depend on both the client running the connection, and the nature of the statement being executed and the transaction is executed inside of.

It would probably make more sense for the controlling process not to run the statement, but just insert the statement text (or the parameters for it, if the statement is always the same except the parameters) into a queue table, and then have the babysitter process actually run it, rather than just monitor it.

There is no good way to monitor for progress for statements other than the ones which have pg_stat_progress_* views defined for them.  You can `strace -y` the backend process and see what blocks of what files is reading, but this is gross, unreliable, requires privileged access, and is nearly impossible to automate.